# Open flash chart not working on iphone and ipad

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, open-flash-chart

I am working of dashboard application in `PHP` and i use `OPEN FLASH CHART-2` for charting framework.
and it also successfully working on every browsers on windows. but when i test it on ios then it failed.I didn't change source any more that can effect it.

Now i can't change my framework.please suggest me some idea or possible way to make it working on IPHONE and IPAD.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with open flash charts, but going by the name I'm assuming they use flash, which doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: @Sameer iOS **DOES** not support flash.